# Hubspot pagination using after in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, pagination, hubspot, hubspot-api

i am building hubspot api, i having trouble paginating the contacts records.
i am using @hubspot/api-client - npm for integration with hubspot and this is the docs for that https://github.com/HubSpot/hubspot-api-nodejs

hubspotClient.crm.contacts.basicApi
.getPage(limit, after, properties, propertiesWithHistory, associations, archived)
.then((results) => {
console.log(results)
})
.catch((err) => {
console.error(err)
})

in this code there is after argument, we can provide contacts id in it, and it will provide the records including and after that particular id.
How do i use this for pagination. or there is any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [API Endpoints documentation](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/contacts) for `GET /crm/v3/objects/contacts` and the data you receive. The `getPage` method returns the following data:

```js
{
  "results": [
    {
      // contact detail here
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "next": {
      "after": "NTI1Cg%3D%3D",
      "link": "?after=NTI1Cg%3D%3D"
    }
  }
}
```

The pagination information is available in `paging.next.after` (if there is a consecutive page). So you can do something like this to iterate through each page:

```js
async function doSomethingWithEachPage() {
  let after = undefined;
  const limit = 10;
  const properties = undefined;
  const propertiesWithHistory = undefined;
  const associations = undefined;
  const archived = false;

  do {
    const response = await hubspotClient.crm.contacts.basicApi.getPage(
      limit,
      after,
      properties,
      propertiesWithHistory,
      associations,
      archived
    );
    // do something with results
    console.log(response.results); // contacts list

    // pick after from response and store it outside of current scope
    after = response.paging?.next?.after;
  } while (after);
}
```

I rewrote the sample code to use async/await so it better works with [do...while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) loop and omitted error handling.

If you are dealing with reasonable small amount of data and have enough of memory, you can also skip the pagination and use the [getAll method](https://github.com/HubSpot/hubspot-api-nodejs#get-all) to load all the data. (In fact, this method does internally a loop similar to the one above.)

Comment: I used this approach. Thanks :)